# Azure App Service: can multiple apps connect to a single back end?

Tags: azure, xamarin, f#, azure-web-app-service

I am building an app ecosystem that consists of three different apps. They all share the same domain model, but they are aimed at different kinds of users. The user database, however, is shared: if you register with one app, you have effectively registered with all three.

This is the (shared) code for signing in using an external provider:

```
member __.SignInAsync (provider: MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider) (client:IMobileServiceClient) (oAuth2: OAuth2Parameters) =
    let completedToSignInResult (completed: AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs) =
        match completed.IsAuthenticated with
        | true -> Authenticated completed.Account
        | false -> NotAuthenticated
    let failedToSignInResult (failed: AuthenticatorErrorEventArgs) =
        AuthenticationFailed(failed.Message, failed.Exception |> Some)
    let authenticator = createAuthenticator oAuth2
    let observable = authenticator.Completed.Select(completedToSignInResult).Merge(authenticator.Error.Select(failedToSignInResult)).FirstAsync()
    AuthenticationState.Authenticator <- authenticator;
    let presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter()
    presenter.Login authenticator
    async {
        try
            let! signInResult = observable |> TaskObservableExtensions.ToTask |> Async.AwaitTask
            match signInResult with
            | Authenticated account ->
                let token = new JObject()
                token.Add("access_token", JToken.FromObject(account.Properties.["access_token"]))
                let! user = client.LoginAsync(provider, token) |> Async.AwaitTask
                return ExternalLoginSucceeded user
            | NotAuthenticated -> return ExternalLoginFailed (String.Format(LocalisedStrings.ProviderSignInFailedTitle, provider), None)
            | AuthenticationFailed (m, e) -> return ExternalLoginFailed (m, e)
        with | ex -> 
            let logger = Locator.Current.GetService<ILog>()
            logger.Error Tag (sprintf "Unexpected sign-in failure with %O" provider) (Some ex)
            let message = String.Format(LocalisedStrings.ProviderSignInFailedTitle, provider)
            return ExternalLoginFailed (message, Some ex)
    }
```

The access token that is retrieved from the presenter is app-specific. However, the Azure Portal *only permits me to register one Facebook or Google App ID and App Secret per app service* (see screenshot).

I can, of course, spin up three different app services, but this seems like a very expensive way to solve the problem. Is there a way to host multiple app IDs and app secrets within a single service, or am I bound by the architecture to spend more money?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out or come up with a workaround?  I am in the same situation.  Any help would be much appreciated.